# Prolog: indicating which predicate is true in an OR rule

Tags: prolog

In SWI-Prolog I have some facts and I have rule that is composed of those facts in a disjunction like so:

```
father(a, b).
mother(a, c).
parent(A, X) :- father(A, X); mother(A, X).
```

This is all fine and all, and when I query I get this:

```
?- parent(a, X).
X = b ;
X = c.
```

I wonder if there's a way to write a rule that indicates which predicate was true for each result, like so:

```
?- parent(a, X).
X = b, R = father ;
X = c, R = mother.
```

Thank you!

Comment: `parent(A, X, R) :- father(A, X), R=father; mother(A, X), R=mother.` ?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, I get warning` Singleton variable in branch: R` and R is not returned when queried.

Comment: Query `parent(a, X, R)`   you can't make a variable appear out of nowhere, afaik.

Comment: @gphilip - the query worked fine for me that TessellatingHeckler proposed.

Comment: Indeed, adding the extra parameter works fine. Thanks. Can you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Terms are an easy way to classify/categorize data, as an alternative to adding another variable, e.g.:

```
father(a, b).
mother(a, c).

parent(father(F), C) :- father(F, C).
parent(mother(M), C) :- mother(M, C).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- parent(P, C).
P = father(a),
C = b ;
P = mother(a),
C = c.
```

Here the parent has retained a categorization of father/mother rule, by creating the corresponding term.

Answer (score 1):

You can also change your predicate to indicate if two persons are related, and how:

```
related(A, B, father(A,B)) :- father(A,B).
related(A, B, mother(A,B)) :- mother(A,B).
```

And maybe add a more general rule that indicates if there is a chain of relationships between to persons.

```
related(A, B, (R1,R2)) :- related(A,Z,R1), related(Z,B,R2).
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to rewrite your program you can trace it instead. This isn't in any way better than the other answers, it is just a different way to do it.

If I trace `mother/2` and `father/2`, and only the `exit` port so I only see the success:

```
?- trace(mother/2, +exit), trace(father/2, +exit).
%         mother/2: [exit]
%         father/2: [exit]
true.

?- parent(a, X).
 T [11] Exit: father(a, b)
X = b ;
 T [11] Exit: mother(a, c)
X = c.
```

The predicates are documented here: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugger

There is a *very nice* tutorial-style overview here: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugoverview

I used this section in particular to answer your question: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=trace-mode-vs-point